# Where do I register redirect URLs on Google Developer's Console?

Tags: xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, xamarin.auth

This is a very simple and straight-forward question, but I really can't find it. Every source I've came across says I should be seeing my redirect URLs here, where I should also be able to add new ones, but as shown in the image, I can't see the redirect URLs next to my OAuth ID:

**my oauth client id**

[image]

I am using Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Auth in case this is relevant information.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`Type: Web application` supports redirect URIs. You are using `Type: Android`, so try to create `Web application` OIDC client type.